# SQL - Find AVG spent of a customer by how much a client spent o

Tags: sql

I have a table of id client, date, services, money_spent
Clients in a single date can have more raws because they bought more services.

I have to create a table where I see the average spent for the clients who come once in the shop, twice, and so on.

[image: This is the table I created]

I would like to group by the people who has count value 1, 2 , 3 and so on to see how much they spent .

At the moment I'm using this query:

`SELECT ID_Client, SUM(Money_spent),COUNT(DISTINCT Date)
FROM Services_Data sd
GROUP BY ID_Client`

Comment: Please don't include data as images. Please use the editor to format the data as text. Then we can use it for testing. Also, please include the ***exact*** results you require from that test data.

Comment: @MatBailie Data-as-images is fine, really - converting an on-screen data-grid to a Markdown table is painful and not a productive use of peoples' time. SO needs better table tools.

Comment: @dai In general the community disagrees. Anything that has a textual representation should not normally be presented as an image. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403699/should-we-disapprove-of-uploading-images-of-tables-when-asking-a-question *(I do agree about the need for improved tools, but disagree that this is a good reason to avoid formatting data. Too many people expect the answerer to copy their data by hand, that's the wrong allocation of labour)*

Answer (score 0):

You just need to aggregate twice.

By placing your query inside brackets (a sub-query) you can then treat it as a table (data set) to run another query on.

```
SELECT
  date_count, 
  SUM(spent) AS spent 
FROM
(
  SELECT ID_Client, SUM(Money_spent) AS spent, COUNT(DISTINCT Date) AS date_count
  FROM Services_Data
  GROUP BY ID_Client
)
  AS client_summary
GROUP BY
  date_count
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the output of your query as the input for another:

```
select times, avg(spent) from (
  select ID_Client, sum(Money_spent) as spent, count(distinct Date) as times
  from Services_data
  group by ID_Client
)
as q1
group by times
```

Comment: Ha! @MatBailie was faster than me :)